# What is a convenient way to destructure imported CSS module for use in a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, less

I am using CSS modules (css-loader & less-loader combination).

I import styles in my Class components like so:

```
    import styles from "./AccountSettings.module.less";
```

And in the JSX I access the styles like so:

```
    className={styles.whatever}
```

But this doesn't seem like the easiest way to do it. How do you achieve similar?

I have attempted to use destructuring, without success:

```
    const {...styles} = this.styles;
```

Comment: What was this destructuring supposed to achieve? You could've equivalently written `const styles = this.styles`

Comment: So that I don't need to type styles. before every classname

Comment: Then use `const whatever = this.styles.whatever` (or `const {whatever} = this.styles;`) so that you can refer to just `whatever`.

Comment: Ok, I as hoping you could spread them so that you didn't have to destructure them one at a time. Thanks

Comment: Ah, now I see what you were asking. No, it's not possible to do that implicitly.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help